# variable ‘qglviewer::QGLVIEWER_EXPORT qglviewer::Constraint’ has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to apply [QGLViewer multiselect](http://libqglviewer.com/examples/multiSelect.html) on 3d object viewed as Linear_cell_complex_for_bgl_combinatorial_map_helper from .off file

my project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/n-m-ya/cm)

it shows errors about using GLViewer/constraint.h as following :

```
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:117:24: error: variable ‘qglviewer::QGLVIEWER_EXPORT qglviewer::Constraint’ has initializer but incomplete type
 class QGLVIEWER_EXPORT Constraint
                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:119:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘public’
 public:
 ^~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:119:1: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘public’
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:118:1: note: to match this ‘{’
 {
 ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:119:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘public’
 public:
 ^~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:2: error: ‘virtual’ outside class declaration
  virtual void constrainTranslation(Vec& translation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(translation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:36: error: variable or field ‘constrainTranslation’ declared void
  virtual void constrainTranslation(Vec& translation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(translation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                    ^~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:36: error: ‘Vec’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:36: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/qglviewer.h:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/draw_linear_cell_complex.h:24,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/mainwindow.h:13,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/vec.h:64:22: note:   ‘CGAL::qglviewer::Vec’
 class CGAL_QT_EXPORT Vec {
                      ^~~
In file included from ../Projects/CM2/manipulatedframesetconstraint.h:3,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/mainwindow.h:36,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:41: error: ‘translation’ was not declared in this scope
  virtual void constrainTranslation(Vec& translation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(translation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:41: note: suggested alternative: ‘QTranslator’
  virtual void constrainTranslation(Vec& translation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(translation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                         QTranslator
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
  virtual void constrainTranslation(Vec& translation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(translation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                                           ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:133:61: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  virtual void constrainTranslation(Vec& translation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(translation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                                             ^~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:2: error: ‘virtual’ outside class declaration
  virtual void constrainRotation(Quaternion& rotation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(rotation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:33: error: variable or field ‘constrainRotation’ declared void
  virtual void constrainRotation(Quaternion& rotation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(rotation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:33: error: ‘Quaternion’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:33: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/camera.h:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/qglviewer.h:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/draw_linear_cell_complex.h:24,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/mainwindow.h:13,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/quaternion.h:69:22: note:   ‘CGAL::qglviewer::Quaternion’
 class CGAL_QT_EXPORT Quaternion {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../Projects/CM2/manipulatedframesetconstraint.h:3,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/mainwindow.h:36,
                 from ../Projects/CM2/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:45: error: ‘rotation’ was not declared in this scope
  virtual void constrainRotation(Quaternion& rotation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(rotation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                             ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘QAction’
  virtual void constrainRotation(Quaternion& rotation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(rotation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                             ^~~~~~~~
                                             QAction
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
  virtual void constrainRotation(Quaternion& rotation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(rotation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                                            ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:142:62: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  virtual void constrainRotation(Quaternion& rotation, Frame* const frame) { Q_UNUSED(rotation); Q_UNUSED(frame); }
                                                              ^~~~~
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:168:44: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
 class QGLVIEWER_EXPORT AxisPlaneConstraint : public Constraint
                                            ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:279:40: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
 class QGLVIEWER_EXPORT LocalConstraint : public AxisPlaneConstraint
                                        ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:299:40: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
 class QGLVIEWER_EXPORT WorldConstraint : public AxisPlaneConstraint
                                        ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:319:41: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
 class QGLVIEWER_EXPORT CameraConstraint : public AxisPlaneConstraint
                                         ^
/usr/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h:336:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 } // namespace qglviewer
 ^
```

all errors were shown in Constraint.h which is already in QGLViewer , So I don't know what is the problem.

I appreciate any help  , thanks

Comment: It seems you mix two different version of QGLViewer: the one provided by CGAL (in directory /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/) and one installed on your system (/usr/include/QGLViewer/). You should use only the CGAL version. Check the paths used by cmake; you can also try to remove the version on your system.

Comment: @gdamiand I removed 

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../lib64/ -lQGLViewer-qt5
but the problem still exist 
notice the included header path user/include/QGLViewer/constraint.h
and when I change it to /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/constraint.h it cannot identify QGLViewer keyword

Comment: everything from `user/include/QGLViewer/` should lead to errors. The right include path is indeed `/usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/`. It should not identify the QGLViewer keyword outside of the CGAL namespace.

Comment: @mgimeno when I use  /usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/
it cannot identify Vec, Frame ,Quaternion in the following code:
virtual void constrainTranslation(qglviewer::Vec &translation, qglviewer::Frame *const frame);
  virtual void constrainRotation(qglviewer::Quaternion &rotation,
                                 qglviewer::Frame *const frame);

Comment: Yes, it is because your calls to those types are wrong. It should be `CGAL::qglviewer::Vec`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To summurize the resolution : 
Use the include files from `/usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/QGLViewer` and not from `/usr/local/include/QGLViewer`

In your code, use the types with the namespace `CGAL::qglviewer::` and not only `qglviewer::`